# The set $\bigcup_{1}^{\infty } \left [ -1+n^{-1} ,1-n^{-1}\right ]$ is identical to $(-1,1)$?

Tags: set-theory

> The set $\bigcup_{1}^{\infty } \left [ -1+n^{-1} ,1-n^{-1}\right ]$ 
>   is identical to
>
> a)$(-1,1)$
>
> b)$(-1,1]$
>
> c)$[-1,1)$
>
> d)$[-1,1]$

Correct Answer: a)$(-1,1)$

Why won't it be d)$[-1,1]$ ?

The last set in the extreme ends is equal to $[-1,1]$    i.e. $\left [ -1+\infty ^{-1} ,1-\infty ^{-1}\right ]$  which is a closed set at both ends.

So, why is the union an open set?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Four answers have been posted below and so far I'm the only one who has up-voted the question. $\qquad$

Comment: There is no "last one."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "last" set in the sequence. The notation $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ means the union of the sets $A_n$ for $n\in\Bbb N$. This is the standard convention. Roughly speaking it means
$$A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup\cdots$$
not
$$A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup\cdots\cup A_\infty$$
(in most cases "$A_\infty$" won't even be meaningful).
Compare summation notation: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ means
$$a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots$$
not
$$a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_\infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $[-1+{1 \over n},1-{1 \over n}] \subset (-1,1)$ for all $n$, hence
the union is also contained in $(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Why *would* it be $[-1,1]\text{?}$ One should not presume something is the answer before one has a reason.

An object is a member of the *union* of some sets if, and only if, it is a member of at least one of the sets. The number $1$ is not a member of any of the sets $[-1+n^{-1}, 1 - n^{-1}].$ Therefore it is not a member of their union. Similarly $-1$ is not a member of any of them.

Comment: Isn't $1$ and $-1$ a memeber of the set $n=\infty $ ??

Comment: @onelessproblem: The $\infty$ doesn't mean that you actually assign $n=\infty$, it just means $n=1,2,3.....$.

Comment: Oh! Got it, thanks!

Comment: @onelessproblem : There isn't any set $n=\infty.$ the notation $\displaystyle \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ means $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3\cup\cdots.$ There is one set for each natural number $n. \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that $\infty$ is not a natural number. When we write "$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$", we mean the union of all $A_n$ for all natural numbers $n$. $\infty$ is not a natural number, so we do not include $A_\infty$. In most cases "$A_\infty$" is not even defined.

The formal definition for $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ is

$$
x \in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \:\Longleftrightarrow\: x\in A_n \text{ for some } n \in \mathbb{N}
$$

So if you claim $1 \in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [-1+n^{-1},1-n^{-1}]$, you must find an $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1 \in A_m$. Think about why you can't find any such $m$.